# Mobile Redirect with pretty URLs in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect my main site (www.mainsite.com) to my mobile site (m.mainsite.com) based on user agent in .htacess.  I used the following code and it redirects to the m.mainsite.com properly.

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Android|AU-MIC|AUDIOVOX|ALCATEL|Blackberry|Blazer|Googlebot-mobile|Handheld|iPhone|iPod|Klondike|LG-|LGE-|Nokia|NokiaN8|Opera\ Mini|PalmOS|PalmSource|Smartphone|Symbian|WebOS|Windows\ CE|Windows\ Mobile|Windows\ Phone|nokia|UP.Link|UP.Browser)
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.mainsite.com/$1
```

However, when taken to the mobile site I seem to be losing the rewritten URL. So what should be m.mainsite.com/page1 goes to something like m.mainsite.com/index.php?url=page1.

I tried rewriting the URL using .htaccess on the mobile site but could not figure out how to remove the part after index.php.  Can anyone help me figure out how to remove "index.php?url=" from m.mainsite.com/index.php?url=page1?

Or would it be easier to figure out how to address this via htaccess in the non-mobile version during the redirect.

Full code looks like:

```html
[code]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainsite.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mainsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\_(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [env=REWRITE_ON:1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Android|AU-MIC|AUDIOVOX|ALCATEL|Blackberry|Blazer|Googlebot-mobile|Handheld|iPhone|iPod|Klondike|LG-|LGE-|Nokia|NokiaN8|Opera\ Mini|PalmOS|PalmSource|Smartphone|Symbian|WebOS|Windows\ CE|Windows\ Mobile|Windows\ Phone|nokia|UP.Link|UP.Browser)
    RewriteRule (.*) http://m.mainsite.com/$1[code]
```

Thanks
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have other rules that's interferring. You need to put all of your redirect rules **before** any internal routing rules. The `index.php?url=page1` looks like your routing rule.

Place the mobile redirect near the top of your htaccess file.

Comment: That is what I tried but that seems to interfere with some of the original rewriting of the urls.  My code looks like the following:

Comment: @GaryGnus you need a `[L]` flag.

Comment: @jon_lin where would the [L] go?

Comment: @GaryGnus to the end of the rule: `RewriteRule (.*) http://m.mainsite.com/$1 [L]`, and make sure that rule is **first**